# Wireless not recognized on my Lenovo G510 laptop on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom, 15.04

How do I enable my Broadcom wireless network adapter on Ubuntu 15.04 offline? I have no LAN access.

Comment: Can you please add the result of `lspci -nn -d 14e4` to the question.  I really just need to see what is between [14e4:????]

Comment: It says 08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14:e4:4365] (rev 01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 64 bit installation, download from a mirror site [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download) and install

If you have 32 bit, [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/i386/bcmwl-kernel-source/download) and install

There should be a copy on the installation media in `/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/`